# Apache poi failed to open word document : NoSuchMethodError using ooxml-shemas-1.0.jar but not with poi-ooxmlshemas-3.8.jar

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml

I'm using Apache poi to manipulate word 2007 documents. I'm using ooxml-shemas-1.0 but have The following message :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFootnotes.getFootnoteList()Ljava/util/List;
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFootnotes.onDocumentRead(XWPFFootnotes.java:84)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.initFootnotes(XWPFDocument.java:235)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:137)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:123)
        at com.scientiweb.utils.WordDocumentProcessor.loadFromTemplate(WordDocumentProcessor.java:74)
```

I have found the method in poi-ooxmlshemas-3.8.jar which I no longer use because I replaced it with ooxml-shemas-1.0.jar (14 mb). What should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! I had to use ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar
The response is in here: http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025

Comment: This Solved me the error, was using 1.4 but giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Since POI 3.7 the ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar is needed you can download it from here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/ooxml-schemas-1.1-sources.jar